Orthographic Projection of Image to Character Texture in Three.js
I'm putting together a Halloween activity for the kids at our school. The plan is to show a "Thriller" music video animation in the gym which has about 10 characters doing the Thriller dance over and over. I have this animation working in Three.js rigged, dancing characters, camera movement, etc.
Now... I want to create a "coloring book" style sheet (see below) that kids can color. Ultimately their drawing will become the "clothes" for one of the 3d characters. In other words, they get to see their drawing dance on screen. (Actually the kids will draw the character twice - once for the front and once as the back. Yeah, sides will be blurry)
I'm so close, but I need help with turning this drawing in to a texture. Right now, I can snap a picture of the kids drawing and my site will use the QR codes to crop/unskew the "scan" into a predictable JPG image.
My question is, how would you do this orthographic(?) isometric(?) projection of the jpg onto the character? I don't even know what words to use.
Can I do it directly in Three.js? I can apply a jpg as the texture, but it obviously doesn't align correctly.
Do i create a UV map(?) of a sample JPG and then swap out the jpg somehow during run-time?  I feel like I'm 80% of the way there but this part is over my head.

